# Correctly locate the desired field from cut operation

Tags: text-processing, ps, cut-command

I have such processes running

```
me   26175  1.7  2.5 1483984 100148 tty2   Sl+  12:49   0:04 /snap/electronic-wechat/7/dist/electronic-wechat-linux-x64/electronic-wechat
me   26237  0.0  0.7 311516 29176 tty2     S+   12:49   0:00 /snap/electronic-wechat/7/dist/electronic-wechat-linux-x64/electronic-wechat --type=zygote --no-sandbox
me   26276  0.2  2.0 550496 81800 tty2     Sl+  12:49   0:00 /snap/electronic-wechat/7/dist/electronic-wechat-linux-x64/electronic-wechat --type=gpu-process --channel=26175.0.1924433599 --mojo-application-channel-token=3E65B226573BBE452FCCE4212BC242ED --no-sandbox --window-depth=24 --x11-visual-id=33 --supports-dual-gpus=false --gpu-driver-bug-workarounds=5,18,56 --gpu-vendor-id=0x0000 --gpu-device-id=0x0000 --gpu-driver-vendor --gpu-driver-version --gpu-driver-date --v8-natives-passed-by-fd --v8-snapshot-passed-by-fd
me   26284  0.2  3.8 1085556 150812 tty2   Sl+  12:49   0:00 /snap/electronic-wechat/7/dist/electronic-wechat-linux-x64/electronic-wechat --type=renderer --no-sandbox --primordial-pipe-token=85EEA61A3C800C4096858B6AE571B4EB --lang=en-US --node-integration=true --enable-pinch --num-raster-threads=2 --content-image-texture-target=3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553 --video-image-texture-target=3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553 --disable-accelerated-video-decode --mojo-channel-token=F13ADFBA9E2E351C09B10692D10BCFBE --mojo-application-channel-token=85EEA61A3C800C4096858B6AE571B4EB --channel=26175.1.78915562 --v8-natives-passed-by-fd --v8-snapshot-passed-by-fd
```

I desire to get column pid using `cut` rather than advanced tools as gwak

```
 ps -aux | grep wechat | sed "s/$USER/me/g" | cut -f 2 | head -n 4 
me   26175  1.2  2.5 1483984 100220 tty2   Sl+  12:49   0:05 /snap/electronic-wechat/7/dist/electronic-wechat-linux-x64/electronic-wechat
me   26237  0.0  0.7 311516 29176 tty2     S+   12:49   0:00 /snap/electronic-wechat/7/dist/electronic-wechat-linux-x64/electronic-wechat --type=zygote --no-sandbox
me   26276  0.1  2.0 550496 81800 tty2     Sl+  12:49   0:00 /snap/electronic-wechat/7/dist/electronic-wechat-linux-x64/electronic-wechat --type=gpu-process --channel=26175.0.1924433599 --mojo-application-channel-token=3E65B226573BBE452FCCE4212BC242ED --no-sandbox --window-depth=24 --x11-visual-id=33 --supports-dual-gpus=false --gpu-driver-bug-workarounds=5,18,56 --gpu-vendor-id=0x0000 --gpu-device-id=0x0000 --gpu-driver-vendor --gpu-driver-version --gpu-driver-date --v8-natives-passed-by-fd --v8-snapshot-passed-by-fd
me   26284  0.1  3.8 1085556 150812 tty2   Sl+  12:49   0:00 /snap/electronic-wechat/7/dist/electronic-wechat-linux-x64/electronic-wechat --type=renderer --no-sandbox --primordial-pipe-token=85EEA61A3C800C4096858B6AE571B4EB --lang=en-US --node-integration=true --enable-pinch --num-raster-threads=2 --content-image-texture-target=3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553 --video-image-texture-target=3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553 --disable-accelerated-video-decode --mojo-channel-token=F13ADFBA9E2E351C09B10692D10BCFBE --mojo-application-channel-token=85EEA61A3C800C4096858B6AE571B4EB --channel=26175.1.78915562 --v8-natives-passed-by-fd --v8-snapshot-passed-by-fd
```

It conclude that the outputs  are not delimited by tabs, then tried space

```
me@host:~$ ps -aux | grep wechat | sed "s/$USER/me/g" | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | head -n 4 




me@host:~$
```

But get bulks of spaces, and the pid is mysteriously locate in field 4

```
me@host:~$ ps -aux | grep wechat | sed "s/$USER/me/g" | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | head -n 4 
26175
26237
26276
26284
me@host~$
```

I am very confused here, how could I decide which field to cut without "trial and error" ?

Comment: `ps -aux | grep wechat | cat --show-tabs` or `ps -aux | grep wechat | cat --show-all`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use `cut` or `awk` at all. `grep` is also [not recommended to be used with `ps`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/74185/85039) because not properly created `grep` query will also include itself in the output.

`pgrep` utility can do the job if you're only interested in PIDs.

```
$ pgrep -f wechat 
8096
8115
```

---

If you're interested in other information, `ps` utility accepts list of columns that it should output in the `-o` option. `pgrep` is a utility for finding processes by name. Thus,what I personally do quite often is this:

```
pgrep -f wechat | xargs -I{} ps  -o pid,ppid,user -p {}
```

`pgrep` utility will look for processes that have `wechat` anywhere in their command-line. `xargs` will pass the output ( the PIDs ) to `ps` and place them to `-p` flag. `-I` will specify what token to use and where in the command the output should be placed.

```
$     pgrep -f wechat | xargs -I{} ps  -o pid,ppid,user -p {}
  PID  PPID USER
 8096  6825 root
  PID  PPID USER
 8115  8096 root
```

There's also `--no-header` option to get rid of column names

```
$ pgrep -f wechat | xargs -I{} ps  -o pid,ppid,user --no-header  -p {}
 8096  6825 root
 8115  8096 root
```

If you want to look only at `electronic-wechat` command, you might want to use `pgrep electronic-wechat`  only without using `-f`

See also `man ps` , specifically "STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS" section for the list of available columns that you can pass to `-o`.

---

If you are interested in *watching* continuously the processes, then you might consider using `top` command, with a filter. You can set one via <kbd>o</kbd> key, view those you set via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>, and reset filters with <kbd>+</kbd> key. Below is the screenshot after I've set a filter and that filter is shown with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>

[image]